# Jenkins Application Running under proxy returns 503 after server reboot

Tags: apache, jenkins, proxy

I don't know if the problem is related to jenkins, java or apache. But since i did a server reboot my jenkins.example.com returns a 503 service unavailable.

---

### What I tried

Restart jenkins, restart apache, reinstall jenkins.

While restarting jenkins I was able to see the default installation page of jenkins but it returned a 503 a few seconds later.

---

### My Settings

Here is my apache.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName jenkins.example.com
    ServerAlias jenkins
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]

</VirtualHost>
```

and apache-ssl.conf

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
      ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName jenkins.example.com
    ServerAlias jenkins
    ProxyRequests Off
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPreserveHost on
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8081/ retry=0 timeout=5 nocanon
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8081
    AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode

        RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
        RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port "443"

SSLCertificateFile /home/staff/x.example.com.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/staff/x.example.com.key
</VirtualHost>
```

Also this is my apache error.log

```
[Wed Mar 21 10:59:16.798407 2018] [proxy:error] [pid 6611] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: HTTP: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:8081 (localhost) failed
[Wed Mar 21 10:59:16.798481 2018] [proxy_http:error] [pid 6611] [client xx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxxx] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: localhost
```

This server has also installed phabricator which is running perfectly after reboot. Only jenkins seemed to crash.

---

### Fixed!

Got this fixed reinstalling jenkins under a new server. I think it was an error with phabricator which was already installed in the same server. Now under the new server, even if I reboot the server, jenkins will show up under jenkins.example.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this fixed by reinstalling jenkins under a new server. I think it was an error with phabricator which was already installed in the same server. Now under the new server, even if I reboot the server, jenkins will show up under jenkins.example.com

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure your `jenkins` to work under the `proxy`. For that to happen, please follow [this link](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/214230/how-do-you-configure-jenkins-to-work-with-a-proxy-server). I haven't tried this on my own. But looks promising. There are more tutorials to configure jenkins under proxy. Hope this will resolve your issue.

Comment: Fixed this by reinstalling jenkins under a new server. Now even if I reboot the server jenkins will come up. Pretty sure it was an error with phabricator which was installed on the same server. Thanks anyway.