# cucumber slack notifier plugin in jenkins is throwing error while publishing report to slack

Tags: jenkins, cucumber, slack

I am trying cucumber slack notifier plugin in jenkins as a post build option but getting this error while publishing report to slack

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:673)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.<init>(SSLSocketImpl.java:477)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(SSLSocketFactoryImpl.java:153)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.SSLProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLProtocolSocketFactory.java:109)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.SSLProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLProtocolSocketFactory.java:156)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:714)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:394)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:178)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:404)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:330)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.slacknotifier.SlackClient.postToSlack(SlackClient.java:60)

Caused: java.lang.RuntimeException: Message could not be posted
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.slacknotifier.SlackClient.postToSlack(SlackClient.java:65)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.slacknotifier.SlackClient.postToSlack(SlackClient.java:54)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.slacknotifier.SlackClient.postToSlack(SlackClient.java:41)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.slacknotifier.CucumberSlackService.sendCucumberReportToSlack(CucumberSlackService.java:33)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.slacknotifier.CucumberSlackPostBuildNotifier.perform(CucumberSlackPostBuildNotifier.java:67)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$2.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:32)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:744)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:690)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.post2(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1073)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:635)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1749)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:543)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)

Build step 'Send Cucumber Report to Slack' marked build as failure
```

Comment: are you under proxy?

Comment: Yes Jenkins is configired on the Linux server machine, However i am able to see the slack notification of the cucumber report when I run the Jenkins on  my local machine.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49405937/5003256